# find matching text and replace next line

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to find a line in a file and replace the next line with a specific value. I tried sed, but it seems to not like the \n. How else can this be done?

The file looks like this:

```
<key>ConnectionString</key>
<string>anything_could_be_here</string>
```

And I'd like to change it to this

```
<key>ConnectionString</key>
<string>changed_value</string>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
sed -i '' "s/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>\n<string><\/string>/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>\n<string>replaced_text<\/string>/g" /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```sh
sed '/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>/!b;n;c<string>changed_value</string>' file
```

`!b` negates the previous address (regexp) and breaks out of any processing, ending the sed commands, `n` prints the current line and then reads the next into the pattern space, `c` changes the current line to the string following the command.

Comment: If there's any osx user interested, you can use gsed insted of sed to make it work (install it with macport or `brew install gnu-sed`)

Comment: Can you breakdown what `!b` `n` and `c` do here?

Comment: @ffledgling, `!b`  negates the previous address (regexp) and breaks out of any processing, ending the sed commands, `n` prints the current line and then reads the next into the pattern space, `c` changes the current line to the string following the command.

Comment: @txulu good heavens, that's helpful.  I was pulling my hair out on my mac.

Comment: @potong whoa thanks! this is precisely what i needed!

Comment: Is there a way to limit the sed action to the first match of the pattern?

Comment: @badkya sure, prefix the above command by `-e` and a space and then add the following extra command set `-e ':a;n;ba'` before the `file` argument. This will read/print all following lines to the end of the file.

Comment: @miken32 Can you direct me to a resource to understand the syntax here? What is meant by "`!b` negates the previous address (regexp) and breaks out of any processing" How do all fit together here? What is the general syntax of the sed instruction?

Comment: @IreshDissanayaka sorry, not my answer. Personally, I'd do this with `awk`. I'm sure the `sed` man page will explain what everything does.

Comment: @IreshDissanayaka the `!` refers to the previous regexp which it negates i.e. if it does not match the regexp. The `b` is a branch command, when it has no argument it breaks out of all sed commands and goes to the end of the current sed cycle. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-flow-control) for further details.

Answer (score 83):

One way:
Sample file

```
$ cat file
Cygwin
Unix
Linux
Solaris
AIX
```

Using sed, replacing the next line after the pattern 'Unix' with 'hi':

```
$ sed '/Unix/{n;s/.*/hi/}' file
Cygwin
Unix
hi
Solaris
AIX
```

For your specific question:

```
$ sed '/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>/{n;s/<string>.*<\/string>/<string>NEW STRING<\/string>/}' your_file
<key>ConnectionString</key>
<string>NEW STRING</string>
```

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "/<key>ConnectionString< ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'` when running `sed '/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>/{n;s/.*/<string>test<\/string>/}' $HOME/Documents/temp.rdp`

Comment: @bswinnerton Ran into the same problem on OS X and this hint helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4904510/479478. So essentially you need to break the curly braces into pieces: ``sed -i '' -e '/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>/ {' -e 'n; s/<string>.*<\/string>/<string>changed<\/string>/' -e '}' your_file``

Comment: sed -i '' -e  '/Unix/ {' -e 'n; s/.*/hihi/' -e '}'

Comment: @EricChen this is amazing... I have no idea how (or better say why) it works... but indeed it does!

Comment: On Linux, in absence of command line utility like mac OS "plutil", this command is useful to manipulate XML based property files (e.g. Info.plist) used within iOS applications.

Comment: Because that's for gnu-sed (brew install gnu-sed), on Mac's sed it needs -i ''

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44836949/1141471

Answer (score 6):

It works. Additionaly is interested to mention that if you write,

```
sed '/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>/!b;n;n;c<string>changed_value</string>' file
```

Note the two n's, it replaces after two lines and so forth.

Comment: @Mausy5043 `-i` does not suppress output. That is the inline replace flag. This flag allows you to directly modify the file.

Comment: @DanielOwsley correct so *effectively* output to the terminal is suppressed ;-)

Comment: That's a a **very** poor way to describe the effect of using `-i`, because "modify the original file" is a far more important effect than "suppress the output". If something is going to alter your files that's important to know (a bad `sed` command could cause you to lose data).

Comment: @Mausy5043 tread lightly with `sed`, if you use `-i` to "suppress" output, you WILL ruin your year... possibly make the news. 
Its like saying: Use `rm -rf /` to instead of `sleep 20` - both will pause for a while before returning the prompt... but with VERY different outcomes. 