# Edit/Match a string n lines below some specific match in Bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a complex problem. Below is the `ndxconfig.ini` file I want to Edit

```
# /etc/ndxconfig.ini will override this file
# if APP_ID is added in service propery, service discovery will be using marathon;
# HOST/PORT specified will override values retrieved from marathon

[MARATHON]
HOSTS = {{ ','.join(groups['marathon'])}}
PORT = 8080
PROTOCOL = http
SECRET = SGpQIcjK2P7RYnrdimhhhGg7i8MdmUqwvA2JlzbyujFS4mR8M88svI7RfNWt5rnKy4WHnAihEZmmIUb940bnlYmnu47HdUHE


[MYSQL]
; APP_ID = /neon/infra/mysql
HOST = {{keepalived_mysql_virtual_ip}}
PORT = 3306
SECRET = tIUFN1rjjDBdEXUsOJjPEtdieg8KhwTzierD48JsgDeYc84DD6Uy5a6kzHfKolq1MNS1DKwlSqxENk33UulJd9DPHPzYCxFm
```

I want to change **specifically marathon protocol conf from http to https**. Not other's protocol conf. I have to match `PROTOCOL = http` **3 lines below the** `[MARATHON]` line. I researched and couldn't find any solution. There's only 1 line below sed solutions.

One idea stuck mine was somehow specially grep `[MARATHON]` and 3 lines below and tail 1 line. I don't know.
How can fix this? Please Help.

Comment: Can you list the one line sed command that you have ?

Comment: sed '/<key>ConnectionString<\/key>/!b;n;c<string>changed_value</string>' file

Comment: @dash-o https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620153/find-matching-text-and-replace-next-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280167)

```
sed '/\[MARATHON\]/{N;N;N;s/http/https/;}' <file>
```

Comment: I guess that works specifically on AIX sed. I've visited that page already.

Comment: Did you try it ? Works with my GNU sed and MacOS sed too

Comment: On stackexchange, it just specifies that on AIX sed, you need to use separate lines but command works on other versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `python` available, you can use [crudini](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/):

```
crudini --set ndxconfig.ini MARATHON protocol https
```

Comment: such awesome python is. ty

Answer (score 0):

This screams for `ed`, which treats the file as a whole, not processing it a line at a time like `sed` (And also doesn't depend on the availability of the non-posix `-i` extension to `sed` for in-place editing of files):

```
ed -s ndxconfig.ini <<'EOF'
/MARATHON/;/^$/ s/^PROTOCOL = http$/PROTOCOL = https/
w
EOF
```

This will replace the PROTOCOL line in the block that starts with a line matching MARATHON and ending with a blank line. The protocol entry can be the second, third, fourth, etc. line; doesn't matter. If the protocol is already https, it won't do anything (Except print a question mark)