# Use Sed to replace next line but keep the white space

Tags: linux, sed

I'm using this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622953/1797263 to replace a version in a pom.xml file.  The problem I'm running into is that it is stripping the preceding whitespace and I want to keep the preceding whitespace. The whitespace could be 2 or 3 tabs or spaces, depending on how the developer formatted the file.

Here is an example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>GROUP</groupId>
            <artifactId>ARTIFACT</artifactId>
            <version>OLD_VERSION</version>
        </dependency>
```

My command: `sed -i '/<artifactId>ARTIFACT<\/artifactId>/!b;n;c<version>NEW_VERSION</version>' pom.xml`

And my output:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>GROUP</groupId>
            <artifactId>ARTIFACT</artifactId>
<version>NEW_VERSION</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is what I would like the replacement to look like:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>GROUP</groupId>
            <artifactId>ARTIFACT</artifactId>
            <version>NEW_VERSION</version>
        </dependency>
```

I read through the GNU Sed manual and could not find anything that would help.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 2):

Using a proper [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) parser :

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -u '/dependency/version' -v NEW_VERSION file.xml
```

### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dependency>
  <groupId>GROUP</groupId>
  <artifactId>ARTIFACT</artifactId>
  <version>NEW_VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query.

#### theory :

> According to the compiling theory, XML/HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of XML/HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1 (check [my wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint) to have newlines delimited output

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/<artifactId>ARTIFACT<\/artifactId>/{n;s/\S.*/<version>NEW_VERSION<\/version>/}' file
```

Overwrite the old version with the new version using the first non-whitespace character as a starting place for the replacing string.

Comment: Me voted down (-1) because giving bad practices to OP.  Edited my answer with explanations 'why not parsing xml with regex'

Comment: @GillesQuenot no problem. I voted you up (+1) for using the best tool.

Comment: I haven't asked a ton of questions on SO, so I'm not exactly sure what the right etiquette here is. This answer does exactly what I was asking for, using the tool i was trying to use.  But there is another answer which is supposedly a 'best practice' on Linux. Which answer should I mark as correct?

Comment: I think this answer is correct. It really answers the question which was about the use of sed. There may be many reason why someone don't (can't) use any other tool.